# Is fprintf thread safe on OS X?

Tags: macos, thread-safety, printf

Is fprintf thread safe on OS X? If so, where is this documented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a good question, although similar questions have been asked here many times.  I was interested in the OSX aspect because I trying to get up to speed on that system myself. (maybe you should add the OSX tag)

I **THINK** fprintf() is thread safe on OSX.  My first reason for this is that the Darwin people were going in that direction as evidenced by their choice to drop the old-school global 'errno' in  favor of the function errno().  For documentation, just follow '/usr/include/errno.h'.   Without that, none of the libc stuff would be thread safe.  Yet the use of the errno() function doesn't prove anything about fprintf().  It's just a start.   I'm sure everyone knows  of at least one situation where Apple didn't carry through with a good idea.

Another reason I believe in the 'thread-safety' of fprintf() is the [**source code**](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-498.1.5/stdio/vfprintf-fbsd.c), which is supposed to be 'the real thing', at least until 10.6 when Apple closed (part / all) of OSX.  Scan that code for "MT-Safe" and you will see a **CLAIM** that the non-locale version of 'vfprintf()' is thread safe.  Again, that doesn't prove anything.  Yet it is a form of documentation, which you wanted.

My final reason to believe fprintf() is thread-safe was a test case.   This doesn't prove much of anything either.  Maybe it proves the buffer space is thread safe.  OK, it was an excuse to write a little program for fun.  Actually, I didn't write it.  I found a skeleton online, and modified it.  The "FLUSH_BUFFER" definition allows you to more clearly see what's happening.  If that macro isn't defined, you get 'sort-of' buffer test  (same text without some line-terminators).  I couldn't figure out a way to arrange a more meaningful collision of the threads.

I'll guess you might be writng to multiple files.  Writing to a single file is probably a better test. The attached program isn't a definitive test.  Although it could be extended, I'm not sure any program could really be definitive.  Bottom line: maybe you should just MUTEX your calls to fprintf().

```
// artificial test for thread safety of fprintf()
// define FLUSH_BUFFER to get a good picture of what's happening, un-def for a buffer test
// the 'pretty print' (FLUSH_BUFFER) output relies on a mono-spaced font
// a writeable file name on the command line will send output to that file
//

#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define FLUSH_BUFFER

#define NTHREAD     5
#define ITERATIONS  3

const char DOTS[] = ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ";
FILE *outFile;

void *PrintHello(void *threadid) {
    long tid;

    tid = (long)threadid;
    for (int i=1; i<=ITERATIONS; i++) {
        long delay = (NTHREAD-tid) * 100000 + (ITERATIONS-i+1) * 10000;
#ifdef FLUSH_BUFFER
        fprintf(outFile, "%*sStart thread  %d iteration %d\n", (tid+1)*4, " ", tid, i);
        usleep(delay);
        fprintf(outFile, "%*sFinish thread %d iteration %d %*.*sw/delay %d\n", 
               (tid+1)*4, " ", tid, i, (NTHREAD-tid+1)*4, (NTHREAD-tid+1)*4, DOTS, delay);
#else
        fprintf(outFile, "Start thread  %d iteration %d   ", tid, i);
        usleep(delay);
        fprintf(outFile, "Finish thread %d iteration %d w/delay %d\n", tid, i, delay);
#endif
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_t threads[NTHREAD];
    char errStr[100];
    int rc;
    long t;

    if(argc > 1) {
        if(! (outFile = fopen(argv[1], "w"))) {
            perror(argv[1]);
            exit(1);
       }
    } else 
        outFile = stdout;

    for(t=0; t<NTHREAD; t++) {
        fprintf(outFile, "In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
        if(rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)t)) {
            sprintf(errStr, "ERROR; pthread_create() returned %d", rc);
            perror(errStr);
            exit(2);
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The POSIX threads specification (AKA Pthreads), which OS X conforms to, requires that stdio functions are thread safe.  It also provides the `flockfile` and `funlockfile` functions to ensure that other threads can't interleave I/O on a FILE * whilst it is locked.

See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/threads.html, specifically under the section titled "**Thread-safety**".